# Why can't I use ES6 template literals with .css() method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ecmascript-6

I am dynamically creating gridblocks where I need to dynamically change the color of every block. I am using jQuery and ES6 but I am currently experiencing a problem dynamically changing the color.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  let y = new Array(20);
  let x = new Array(29);
  let colors = Array.of('red','green','orange','pink','purple');
  let xCoordinate = 20
  for (let block of x) {
    let randomColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
    let gridBlock = $(`<div class='blockattribute' style=left:${xCoordinate}px></div>`);
    gridBlock.addClass('topcoordinate');
    gridBlock.css(`{background-color:${randomColor}}`);
    $('#colorgrid').append(gridBlock);
    xCoordinate += 20;
  }
});
```

The problem I am experiencing is this part `gridBlock.css(`{background-color:${randomColor}}`);` This code is not setting the color at all. Am I missing something here?

Comment: `gridBlock.css({"background-color":randomColor});` - The `.css()` method expects an object or two strings, not a string containing `{}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're passing this

```
`{background-color:${randomColor}}`
```

which will become a string (not an object)

```
'{background-color:YOUR_COLOR}'
```

But [css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) expects either a properties object like

```
element.css({ 'background-color': 'red' })
```

Meaning you should do

```
gridBlock.css({ 'background-color': randomColor })
```

or you can pass 2 strings like

```
gridBlock.css('background-color', randomColor);
```

You don't really need template strings for this use case.

Answer (score 1):

Use template literal for color only and *camelCase* for hyphenated properties

```
gridBlock.css({backgroundColor:`${randomColor}`});
```

And you don't need template literal at all.

```
gridBlock.css({backgroundColor:randomColor});
```

Comment: Why would you say `:\`${randomColor}\`` and not `:randomColor`?